# Filtering a xts object from one year to the next

Tags: r, time-series, xts

If I have a 10-year daily xts time series, starting on 1985-01-01 and ending on 1994-12-31, how can I calculate the sum of values for the interval starting on Nov 1 and ending on Mar 31 of the next year, through out the series?

```
dates <- seq(from = as.Date("1985-01-01"), to = as.Date("1994-12-31"), by = 1)
data <- rnorm(length(dates))
my.ts <- xts(x=data, order.by=dates)
```

I need to get

```
my.ts2[1] = sum(my.ts[1985-11-01 to 1986-03-31])
my.ts2[2] = sum(my.ts[1986-11-01 to 1987-03-31])
my.ts2[3] = sum(my.ts[1987-11-01 to 1988-03-31])
and so on
```

Note: There are no Feb-29 in the original time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This aggregates by successive groups, separated at Nov 1. and Apr 1.
The first row of the results is an incomplete "in" group, then an "out" group, then an "in", and so on.

```
library(xts)

set.seed(1)
dates <- seq(from = as.Date("1985-01-01"), to = as.Date("1994-12-31"), by = 1)
data <- round(rnorm(length(dates)), 2)
my.ts <- xts(x=data, order.by=dates)

d <- as.POSIXlt(index(my.ts))
nov1 <- d$mon == 10 & d$mday == 1
apr1 <- d$mon == 3 & d$mday == 1
id <- cumsum(nov1+apr1)

agg <- cbind(
  aggregate(index(my.ts), list(id), function(x) as.character(range(x))),
  aggregate(my.ts, id, sum)
)

agg <- data.frame(
  id=agg[[1]], 
  start=agg[[2]][,1], 
  end=agg[[2]][,2], 
  sum=agg[[3]]
)

# To filter for only the "in" groups
agg[endsWith(agg$end, "-03-31") | endsWith(agg$start, "-11-01"),]
#    id      start        end    sum
# 1   0 1985-01-01 1985-03-31   9.77
# 3   2 1985-11-01 1986-03-31  -5.76
# 5   4 1986-11-01 1987-03-31 -10.54
# 7   6 1987-11-01 1988-03-31  -5.81
# 9   8 1988-11-01 1989-03-31   9.26
# 11 10 1989-11-01 1990-03-31  -6.42
# 13 12 1990-11-01 1991-03-31  -5.78
# 15 14 1991-11-01 1992-03-31 -17.57
# 17 16 1992-11-01 1993-03-31  20.03
# 19 18 1993-11-01 1994-03-31  16.06
# 21 20 1994-11-01 1994-12-31  -5.76
```

Comment: Thanks. But I only need the sum for 11-01 to 03-31.  How can I eliminate the others?

Comment: @San-Diego-WX: All the odd-numbered rows are 11-01 to 03-31

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Why are some of the answers disappearing?  There seemed to be 2 answers to my question at some point

Comment: @San-Diego-WX: Yes there was another answer. I sometimes remove my answer if I find a fatal flaw in it that I can't easily fix, so maybe that happened here too?

Comment: @San-Diego-WX: I've been going back and forth between different approaches, but can't find anything easier. Leap years and the change of year within your capture period are the main complicating matters. I added a way to filter for the sums you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two liner to do that with the reproducible input in the Note at the end.

Let `ok` be TRUE for the dates that are within November to March and FALSE otherwise. Then use `collapse::groupid` (or `data.table::rleid` or `dplyr::consecutive_id`) to uniquely identify each run and use `[ok]` to drop the dates outside of the aforementioned intervals.  Use `ave` to identify the last date in each November to March interval and sum over each interval using `aggregate.zoo` giving zoo series `res`.  (If desired use `as.xts(res)` or `fortity.zoo(res)` to convert that to an xts object or data frame.)

```
library(xts)
library(collapse) # groupid

ok <- cycle(as.yearmon(time(my.ts))) %in% c(11:12, 1:3)
res <- aggregate(my.ts[ok], ave(time(my.ts[ok]), groupid(ok)[ok], FUN = max), sum)
res
```

giving

```
1985-03-31   8.4324478
1986-03-31   9.4125674
1987-03-31  17.7676264
1988-03-31 -16.3924959
1989-03-31 -22.1016964
1990-03-31 -11.3095770
1991-03-31   2.8736790
1992-03-31  -8.0894314
1993-03-31   6.2141083
1994-03-31   2.8035838
1994-12-31   0.9928396
```

### Note

We used this input with `set.seed` to make it reproducible.

```
set.seed(123)
dates <- seq(from = as.Date("1985-01-01"), to = as.Date("1994-12-31"), by = 1)
data <- rnorm(length(dates))
my.ts <- xts(x=data, order.by=dates)
```